# how to expand TextField height when we are entering text in it

Tags: java-me

```
//#style sendMessage 
        txtSendMessage = new TextField("Send Message","",150, TextField.ANY);
        this.smsScreen.append(txtSendMessage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what language, java?

You can add an event listener to the textbox and every time, some one types a char, you can check the size of the text that the texbox is holding and change the style of the textbox.

If you want a more precise answer, please supply some more info about the programming language, what type of gui you are using etc. etc.